# Optionally reference a single table from multiple other tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm a total beginner to Flask and SQLAlchemy and I'm stuck on what should be quite a simple problem.

My application includes the following two tables:

```
class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(), primary_key=True)
    # more columns

class Person(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(), primary_key=True)
    # more columns
```

Unnecessary columns have been removed for brevity. I'm required to add a third kind of table, `Description`, which has a number of properties. `Item` and `Person` can *optionally* have descriptions.

This is what I've done:

```
class Description(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(), primary_key=True)
    text = db.Column(db.BLOB, nullable=False)
    # some other properties

class Item(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(), primary_key=True)
    description_id = db.Column(UUIDType(), db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), nullable=True)
    description = db.relationship('Description')

class Person(db.Model)
    id = db.Column(UUIDType(), primary_key=True)
    description_id = db.Column(UUIDType(), db.ForeignKey('tags.id'), nullable=True)
    description = db.relationship('Description')
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way to approach the problem, particularly since the `description_id` column is nullable but the `description` relationship is not.

Is this correct? And if so (doubtful), is there a better way to solve the problem?

Comment: Why can't you make the `description` field as a `column`? Are there any details?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Because `description` needs to have it's own columns, like created date and time, created user etc.